# How I can allow JMS to use port 7676

Tags: java, spring, jms, apache-camel

So i have this problem with running a application which use JMS, I did everything that was described here [Transparent Asynchronous Remoting via JMS](http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2011/03/transparent-asynchronous-remoting-via.htmlrent-asynchronous-remoting-via.html)

here is the Exception i am getting:

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is com.sun.messaging.jms.JMSException: [C4003]: Error occurred on connection creation [localhost:7676]. - cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316) ~[spring-jms-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:168) ~[spring-jms-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:469) ~[spring-jms-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:175) ~[camel-jms-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:355) ~[camel-jms-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:309) ~[camel-jms-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:99) ~[camel-jms-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:91) ~[camel-core-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultAsyncProducer.process(DefaultAsyncProducer.java:37) ~[camel-core-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.CamelInvocationHandler.invoke(CamelInvocationHandler.java:65) ~[camel-core-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at $Proxy18.inputCAChain(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at pl.os.test.ws.endpoint.osCaEndpoint.getCAChain(osCaEndpoint.java:66) ~[osaEndpoint.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.MethodEndpoint.invoke(MethodEndpoint.java:134) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:229) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:233) [spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173) [spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88) [spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59) [spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:221) [spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.30.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.30.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.30.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.30.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.30.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168) [catalina.jar:7.0.30.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.30.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929) [catalina.jar:7.0.30.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.30.A]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) [catalina.jar:7.0.30.A]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.30.A]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.30.A]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.30.A]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.7.0_09]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_09]
```

I have absolutely no expirience either JMS or Camel, so my guess that JMS is not allowed to use port 7676 if it is so how i can fix this? If it is not the cause do you have any hint what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a broker running on this port? You can verify that the broker is running with telnet:

```
telnet localhost 7676
```

Comment: I am the dumbest person ever. Ofc it was not! Thank you mbelow